# Checking whether an address exists. Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there a way to check whether an address you pass into Google Maps to get direction with the URL scheme exists?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a geocode request, and then see if you get a response of `OK` (the address could be converted into a location, so it exists), or `ZERO_RESULTS` (the address doesn't exist). Presumably when you start the Google Maps app with a URL scheme, Google uses the same geocoder internally to look up the address.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/